# Owl Carousel Loop Issues, whitespace when reaching end and slides sliding off changing to slides coming in

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

Now, the issue I'm having is that when I'm dragging the elements with my mouse and release, as I release the element changes briefly to the element that is being scrolled in. The expected behavior would be that the leftmost slide remains purple, but it turns black, the color of the slide incoming.

[image]

[image]

I'm also having an issue with the loop on the carousel is that when I have loop it doesn't loop right away, it leaves a white space until all the elements disappear, then loops back to the beginning. I want it to be continuous. Below is a picture of the white space that happens when I scroll to the end of the slides.

[image]

[image]

```js
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
  margin: 0,
  loop: true,
  items: 4,
  navText: '',
  autoplayTimeout: 6000,
  autoplaySpeed: 1000,
  navSpeed: 1000,
  dotsSpeed: 1000,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  mouseDrag: true,
  nav: true,
});
```

```css
.slide {
  width: 240px;
  min-height: 350px;
  max-height: 350px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.0/css/bulma.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="slide" style="background-color: black;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color: red;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style=" background-color: green;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style=" background-color: blue;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style=" background-color: purple;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color: orange;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color: darkcyan;"> Your Content </div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-color: darkblue;"> Your Content </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't seem to be outputting anything.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why, but it isn't showing up on codepen either

Comment: I just checked. You seem to have forgotten to include the owl carousel css files. There are 2 CSS files that you need to include for Owl Carousel. Without which it won't show up. Also make sure your JS files are all imported at the end of the body tag. First one being jQuery because your other JS files weill need jQuery.

Comment: I tested out your code locally. It seems to be working fine. Try including the 2 CSS files. 
Official docs - https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html
CDN - https://cdnjs.com/libraries/OwlCarousel2

Comment: yup, just add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">` and it runs as expected from what I can see. are there any other css rules being applied that might be contributing to the problem?